# How can my default project setting be US zone & ASIA region at the same time using Google cloud shell?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I set the default zone to us-west2-b. In the next command I gave the Region as Asia & there was no error. The Region was set successfully.
I could create a compute instance with these default settings without any issue. How can this work ?[DefaultSettings-Google Cloud Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTLGn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Cloud, you have 3 types of Compute Engine resources:

- Global
- Regional
- Zonal

Have a look at the doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/global-regional-zonal-resources) to see which resources fall under which category.

When you create or interact with a resource via the `gcloud` cli tool, you are asked to specify either a `--region` or `--zone` flag, depending on the resource category (not both, it's not about ensuring that both flags you provided match).

Since providing one of these flags for every command can be tedious, gcloud allows you to provide default values for `compute/region` and `compute/zone`. If you don't provide the required flag to the command, the default is used. If you do, the provided flag will overrides the default.

Note that, looking at the screenshot you provided, you specified a zone as `compute/region`, which isn't correct. The value correctness isn't check when you set the default value but only when a given command is executed. In your case, if you try to create a regional resource without specifying the `--region` flag, the command should fail.

Comment: Thanks LundinCast. What I understood is, compute instance is created at zonal level & hence the zone value overrides the default region set in the config. Whatever zone we set while creating, its parent region will override the default region.